# Cannot subscript a value of a type AnyObject, in Swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

I have this line of code, and I want to extract the "title" key:

```
var title = jParams["title"] as! String
```

However it wont let me compile, and if I get this error message in red:

> Cannot subscript a value of a type AnyObject with an index of type String

When  show the contents of jParams in the log with `println(jParams)` I get the following content:

```
INCOMING LIST PARAMETERS (jParameters)
Optional({
    title = "Example List";
    values =     (
                {
            id = 1;
            name = "Line 1";
        },
                {
            id = 2;
            name = "Line 2";
        },
                {
            id = 3;
            name = "Line 3";
        }
    );
})
```

I am new to Swift so I am not familiar with the details of handling JSON to deal with these type of problems. What could be wrong?

```
//jParams comes from a JSON server response
var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
            if data != nil {
                var jdata = JSON(data: data!)
                var jParams=jdata["responseData"]["extraData"]["params"]
```

Comment: How is jParams defined? What type is it?

Comment: Hi @MarcosCrispino I have added a piece of code to the answer about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your edit it looks like you're using SwiftyJSON.

If that is indeed the case, you can help the compiler to know what's in the dictionary by using SwiftyJSON's `dictionaryValue` property:

```
let jParams = jdata["responseData"]["extraData"]["params"].dictionaryValue
```

Then you should be able to access your values without downcasting:

```
let title = jParams["title"]
```

because SwiftyJSON will have inferred the right type for the values.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked so. Additionally, if you still want an optional Dictionary, you can use the `dictionary` property.

Comment: Works like charm! I was indeed using SwiftyJSON, ".dictionaryValue" was the key, thanks.